# How can I create Servlet project with maven in Intellij Idea?

Tags: java, servlets, web-applications

I have created a maven project in Intellij Idea. I also added jetty's maven dependency to pom file.
What should I do then to create servlet project? 
Should I create **webapp\WEB-INF\web.xml** folder in **main\java** manually? or there is some maven plugins which I must add to **Pom.xml** file and after clicking install in Lifecycle, related folders and files will be created automatically?

**Pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.c.helloWorldMavenServlet</groupId>
<artifactId>helloWorldMavenServlet</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>


<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>8.1.16.v20140903</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>



</project>
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to use maven archetype to create project:
**org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-webapp**
Then you should create directory java in **src/main**,then right click-> **Mark Directory As -> Sources Root**.
By default, you have **web.xml** in version **2.3** so that's mean you cannot user CDI for example.
If you want to change it go to **File->Project Structure->Facets(or Modules)** and then delete Web Descriptor from Deployment Descriptors and then add new **web.xml**(+) and choose version **3.1**.

I hope it should work. At this moment I don't know any other way to achieve that